# File (mp3) concatenation issues using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp3, codec

I want to concatenate some MP3 files using the [FFmpeg concatenation protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#concat).

Here is a successful try:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i "concat:audio/it/ci.mp3|audio/it/èsse.mp3|audio/it/cu.mp3|audio/it/u.mp3|audio/it/tre.mp3|audio/it/zero.mp3|audio/it/cinque.mp3|audio/it/quattro.mp3|audio/it/tre.mp3|audio/it/otto.mp3|audio/it/tre.mp3" -c copy audio/it/CSQU3054383.mp3 -y

$ ll audio/it/CSQU3054383.mp3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 giorgio 26K Nov  9 16:16 audio/it/CSQU3054383.mp3
```

So far, all is OK!

BTW, all (Mp3) files have the same codecs, so MP3 FFmpeg concatenation protocol runs as expected!

---

Now, I want to insert a pause file `audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3`, between each previous files:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -loglevel panic -i "concat:audio/it/ci.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/èsse.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/cu.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/u.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/tre.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/zero.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/cinque.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/quattro.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/tre.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/otto.mp3|audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3|audio/it/tre.mp3" -c copy audio/it/CSQU3054383.mp3 -y
$
```

This command run apparently without any error, but the output file (`audio/it/CSQU3054383.mp3`) is not generated at all.

**Question 1 (minor):

Why doesn't FFmpeg report any error and doesn't generate the expected output?**

In fact, I already experienced that FFmpeg, in some circumstances, fails without saying why :(

---

I suspect the problem happens because the file `audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3` doesn't have a constant bit rate (CBR), as other files, e.g.:

```sh
$ mediainfo  audio/it/ci.mp3
General
Complete name                            : audio/it/ci.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 2.06 KiB
Duration                                 : 528 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 32.0 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Duration                                 : 528 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 32.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 24.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (576 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 2.06 KiB (100%)

$ ffprobe audio/it/ci.mp3
ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mp3 @ 0x564491288080] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'audio/it/ci.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:00.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
```

Instead, the inserted pause file has a variable bit rate, as mediainfo states:

```sh
$ mediainfo audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3
General
Complete name                            : audio/it/PAUSE_2.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 8.29 KiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Writing library                          : LAME3.100

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 24.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 8.06 KiB (97%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
```

Here my Bash script I used to generate the pause:

```sh
$ cat com/pause
#!/bin/bash

# https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-anullsrc
# https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Examples-1

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo
    echo "create a pause, a silence audio file (MP3) of specified number of milliseconds"
    echo
    echo "usage: $0 <time duration (in seconds)> <directory path>"
    echo
    echo "example: $0 2"
    echo "example: $0 0.5 tmp/"
    echo
    exit
fi

timeDuration=$1
directoryPath=$2

suffix=mp3

# https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Limiting%20the%20output%20bitrate
#https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3
bitrate=32k
samplingRate=24000
outputFile="${directoryPath}PAUSE_${timeDuration}.${suffix}"

  #-b:a $bitrate -minrate $bitrate -maxrate $bitrate -bufsize $bitrate \
ffmpeg \
  -f lavfi \
  -i anullsrc=r=$samplingRate:cl=mono \
  -t $timeDuration \
  -b:a $bitrate -minrate $bitrate -maxrate $bitrate \
  -codec:a libmp3lame \
  $outputFile -y

echo
echo "created file: $outputFile"
echo
```

Unfortunately, the created file seems with a variable bit rate and not with a constant bit rate (CBR), as expected ( -b:a ... ):

```sh
$ com/pause 2
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc=r=24000:cl=mono':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 24000 Hz, mono, u8, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_u8 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'PAUSE_2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 24000 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libmp3lame
size=       8kB time=00:00:02.01 bitrate=  33.7kbits/s speed= 192x
video:0kB audio:8kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.870640%

created file: PAUSE_2.mp3
```

**Question 2:**

What's wrong in my Bash script (why doesn't it generate a CBR file?
How can I generate an silence pause file (silence of N milliseconds) with the exact settings of previous files?

Comment: What's the output of `ffmpeg -i` for the file before and after?

Comment: before: added ffprobe. After: file not created! (ffmpeg bad error management).
Question 2: II solved setting in my script bitrate=64k): to have a constant bit rate (CBR) works -b:a 64k (bit rate >= 64000), but -b:a 32k not works (it create a VBR). Not fully clear to me.